# Webpart Filter on Infopath Form Library

Tags: web-part, infopath, filter, library

I have a webpart page that displays an infopath form, with the associated form library in list view next to the form. I'm trying to create a Sharepoint List filter webpart to show only forms with a selected attribute. I believe I've made all the appropriate connections, but the list does not filter when the webpart filter is used. Does the webpart filter not work with Form Libraries as it would with a normal document list?

Many Thanks.

K.S.